# Problems with degrees of uncertainty

Tags: java

So I have code that takes sqrts and takes arctans and converts from radians to degrees, which leaves me with not quite precise values. Short of using a CAS, is there anything I can do to make checks on whether or not things are equal without rounding them?

Comment: If the difference of two `double` is less than, say, 0.0001 then they are equal.

Comment: It might be usefull to post your code... But with doubles, you can never be sure they are equal, so you have to ckeck for `abs(a - b)<0.00001` or something.

Comment: @Davidvanrijn Ideally I want to not have to round, and also I may be looking at a few trillion iterations, so rounding at all will heavily skew the end result.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that CAS means Computer Algebra System<sup>1</sup> ...

The practical way to test if two numbers are equal when there is the possibility of errors in calculation (or measurement precision) is to check if the difference is less than a "delta" that is determined by the estimated error in the calculated numbers.

The problem is finding a good (enough) estimate for the error.  Pulling a number out of the air (like `0.0001`) can give you false positives or false negatives.  To do it properly, you actually need to do a numeric analysis *of your calculations* to get a reliable estimate.

---

Obviously ... the amount of time you spend on this problem should depend on how important it is that you get the "right" answer; i.e. what the consequences of a false positive or negative would be to the program ... and the people using it.

---

<sup>1 - For the record, a CAS probably wouldn't help you here.  The kind of problems that involve this type of calculation typically don't have algebraic solutions.</sup>

Comment: The calculations have to do with bouncing around an elipse and checking for when it returns to the original point, so if it ever does, wouldn't a CAS (and yes I did mean Computer Algebra System) eventually depict the values simplified and so then the same?

Comment: It might work, but there are two questions.  1) Is there an analytical solution at all?  2) Could a (dumb) CAS find that solution?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the CAS wouldn't need to even be able to do calculus, but just in case, you tell me:

EDIT: Code is like 500 characters too long, lemme screencap. http://prntscr.com/91ezde